# Manipulate dataLayer using Google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Is it possible to get a value from the dataLayer, modify it and push it back to the dataLayer?

I used this custom HTML for that, but it returns NaN (Not a Number), thoughts?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  amsdataLayer.push({
    'roomcount' : 6*('roomcount').float()
  });
    
})(); 
</script>
```

Comment: roomcount is currently in the dataLayer and it has the value '1'. I tried to read the value, multiply it by 6 and push it back to the dataLayer.

Comment: if you use just 6 there, it would over write the current value 1 and the roomcount will be equal to 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If roomcount is currently in the dataLayer (for precisions sake: if it is in the dataLayer and you access it via a GTM variable) you need to use double curly brackets to access it, i.e. `{{roomcount}}`. Currently you are applying your calls to the literal string "roomcount", which does not result in a number (also, is there really a float() method for numbers in JS ? Currently I can only think of parseFloat which has a different syntax).

Also you need a (native or custom) event to make GTM aware of changes to the dataLayer.

Comment: Dear Eike, thank you very much! 

This worked.

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var hodor = ({{DL_roomcount}})
  hodor = 6*hodor
  amsdataLayer.push({
    'roomcount' : hodor
  });
    
})(); 
</script>

Thank you Eike!

Comment: no need for float and parseFloat is the correct way to turn string into float in javascript, thanks Eike